# What implication/intuitive understanding can one derive from the fact that the mean is greater than the variance in a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I solved for the mean and variance of a binomial distribution, fairly straightforward. Again, it is easy to mathematically see that the mean is always greater than the variance. What does this mean intuitively? What advantage do you derive from this fact? It just can't be purposelessly lying out there?

Comment: Not a lot except that a Poisson distribution has its variance equal to its mean, so a binomial distribution is less dispersed than a Poisson distribution with the same mean.

Comment: That helps a bit. Thanks!